# How to add css to my page in Plone?

Tags: css, content-management-system, plone, plone-4.x, plone-3.x

I am not being able to apply css styles to my page in Plone. I am new to Plone, usually I use wordpress.

Comment: So, how could we help you?

Comment: Can you help me telling how to style my page in plone cms.

Answer (score 2):

This document walks through making basic style changes to Plone. It focuses on fonts and colors but if you're comfortable with CSS you will see that you can change other aspects as well.
http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/change-the-font-colors.html

To fully theme Plone, look into Diazo, more information is available here: http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/theming/index.html